# djangocms-installer not asking setup questions

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-templates, django-cms

When creating a new django-cms project, the installer does not ask any setup questions.

runserver starts fine, and a page is produced at 127.0.0.1:8000 but the page is blank instead of a demo page.

Beyond this, adding a new template to the template directory does not appear as an option when adding a new page to the site.

The tutorial at [docs.django-cms](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/introduction/install.html) seem entirely different to what I'm experiencing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems they've changed the installer but have not updated the docs:  https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/5737

From the link:

> We changed the installer to setup the project using all defaults without input by default.
>
> This was a design decision based on user feedback as some of these options can be confusing to newcomers.
>
> To get the wizard, you can pass the -w option to djangocms -f -p . mysite